# Cannot drag text into a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, window

I'm trying to set up a WPF window so that it can accept different types of data via `Drag and Drop`. If I make a new project and set the window to the following:

```
<Window x:Class="DropShare.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="Window_DragEnter">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And set the code-behind to:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I only ever get `DragEnter` firing for files. It *never* fires for anything else - text, images, etc.

Is there something I'm missing? All the tutorials I've read have seemed to suggest this is all that's needed as the `DragEnter` event handler let's me state what I accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your code works fine for me. But try this...

In your Window:

```
<Label Background="Purple" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Drag from here!" MouseDown="Label_MouseDown"/>
```

and in your code behind:

```
private void Label_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, "This is just a test", DragDropEffects.All);
}
```

Then drag from the label into the window and see if your event fires.

If this works, it may have something to do with the permissions level between Visual Studio and your outside environment (possibly).

See:

https://superuser.com/questions/59051/drag-and-drop-file-into-application-under-run-as-administrator

Comment: That did work.

It seems like it was a permissions thing. I was able to drag things in from Chrome but not IE10. I'm going to use Silverlight instead as it seems to work with everything.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF drag and drop feature always has to deal with `DragDrop` Class, Please check [here](http://gergelykoncz.com/2011/02/16/implement-drag-and-drop-operations-within-and-across-applications/) how to do drag and drop across applications

Comment: Thanks, but that's more for **starting** a drag and drop operation within my application.